# I am looking for a direct long. to X lat to Y map of earth

Tags: coordinate-system

Occasionally I like to drop raw coordinate data into excel and do a scatterplot. It comes out quite a bit like cylindrical projection but not quite. The distortion near the poles is a bit more pronounced.

1. What is This raw projection called and
2. Does anyone have a reasonable map of earth using this projection?

I promise not to publish using the ugly thing or corrupt young minds with it. I just would like it for my reference.

Comment: Geographic is the name for the projection, but this has many datums (where you start counting from) and spheroids (models of the earth) what coordinate system are your input coordinates in / where do they come from?

Comment: Oh just things like the coordinates of all macdonalds restaurants in the world or every public library in America. the sets are in decimal latitude,longitude.

Comment: Where are they sourced from? If it is recent data and/or data to be used with GPS coordinates there's a good bet that it's in WGS84/Geographic. If you have QGIS open up an open layer and set your project to WGS84/Geographic and see how some of your sample points line up... hint, look at different cities and 1 or 2 points in each. If you don't have QGIS then download it, it's free - and works in windows, linux even mac. http://www.qgis.org/en/site/

Comment: I would just like a map not to learn a new software. Just a .png would be fine.

Comment: Learn the new software and make your own, as general or detailed as you want. There is reasonable open data available to make the map... but that's not what the test is about, the test as suggested in the last comment was to determine if the points are in WGS84/Geographic. Having a map is one thing but making it align to your data is quite another. Another thing that needs to be considered is the scale you map would be viewed at, this would affect the rows/columns in your png. Generally speaking this site is about advise, not data, it's unlikely that anyone will give you data - only words.

Comment: It is also known as a Plate-Carre projection.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying geographic coordinates (i.e.lat/long) as if they were 2D cartesian coordinates is similar to using the "Plate carrée" coordinate system (also called [equirectangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection)).

However, you will have a scale factor difference so it is not straightforward to put your points on top of the map. Therefore the suggestion to use a specific software is a good suggestion. To make it easy, I suggest that you use some [online tools to convert your excel sheet to kml](https://www.earthpoint.us/ExcelToKml.aspx), then you can add this kml to Google Earth (or google map) base map.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is called the Equirectangular projection, plate caree or Geographic projection. This last name is nearly worthless in the age of Google. It is an ancient method associated with Ptolemy and very commonly used by nasa and other scientific endeavors where its size and  shape distortions don't matter as much as ease.
2. Just Google plate caree and click on images there are tons of them. No specialized software or conversions needed just make sure your chart's range and domain are [-180,180],[-90,90], your plot area fill is set to no fill and you know how to use the corner pulls to scale.